# Customize Routes for ASP.NET Razor UI libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I am writing a Razor UI library (similar to the default Identity UI library) for ASP.NET that provides UI to select localization for the client.

That is a pretty useful UI, so I am writing it as a library and plan to put into multiple of my web projects.

How do I in the consuming web page customize the Route that is used for the Razor UI library controllers and views?

The default Identity UI library uses an area `identity` and has all routes underneath that area. What if I want to have a different route? Is there a way to remap the MVC router to map a certain path to a specific area?